Downloading symlink without using jfrog cli
Is there a way to download a symlink from jfrog without using the jfrog cli?
I can use jf rt download --url=... --user=... -password=... example.txt --validate-symlinks=true and this will download a symlink thats been uploaded perfectly okay.
However, I am looking to use something like CMake FetchContent to achieve the same effect and have it download the file the symlink points to rather than the zero size file itself.
The main purpose of this is because I am currently downloading a file from artifactory using FetchContent so don't need a username and password to download that, but using jfrog download with --validate-symlinks will and I want to avoid that.
